# Execute Oracle Function from C#

Tags: c#, oracle, function

I have created a function Funt() that returns a CLOB. To call this function, I used "select Funt() from DUAL". When I execute this query directly from SQL Developer, it finishes fairly quickly. But when I execute this query using OracleDataReader and OracleDataAdapter, both of them didn't finish. Any idea?

**Edit 1**: Here is the code. It hanged in reader.Read().

```
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("select Funt() from DUAL", oraConnection);

OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    using (OracleLob lob = reader.GetOracleLob(0))
    { 
        using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(lob,Encoding.Unicode))
        {
            String msg = sr.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**: Created a simple function just returns a CLOB, and it works with this code.

**EDIT 3**: It appears that running function in this way from .NET is slower than in SQL Developer.

Comment: Can you show us the code?